# Unable to catch error in PowerShell script, while using quest active roles to query active directory

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I have a script which returns the location of a list of computers within AD. This works fine for my current domain and if I specify "-searchroot" it works for the others.

If I query a computer not on the correct domain, with 'get-qadcomputer' it does not return any information to the console, so need a method to catch and try alternatives?

I have tried this, which just works for all computer in DC=Domain1 (my current domain):

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
$strPath = "C:\sample.xlsx"

$objExcel = new-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strPath)
$worksheetIn = $workbook.sheets.item("Asset")
$worksheetOut = $workbook.sheets.item("Asset")
$intRowMax =  ($worksheetIn.UsedRange.Rows).count
$Columnnumber = 1

For($intRow = 2 ; $intRow -le $intRowMax ; $intRow++) {
Try 
{
$name = $worksheetIn.cells.item($intRow,$ColumnNumber).value2
"Querying $name...$introw of $intRowMax" 
$OU = Get-QADcomputer -searchroot 'OU=Workstations,DC=DOMAIN1'-LdapFilter "(CN=$Name)"`
| ft Location -HideTableHeaders
$Out = Format-list -InputObject $OU | out-string
$worksheetOut.cells.item($intRow,6) = "$Out"
    }
Catch
    {
$name = $worksheetIn.cells.item($intRow,$ColumnNumber)
"Querying $name...$introw of $intRowMax" 
$OU = Get-QADComputer -SearchRoot 'OU=Workstations,DC=DOMAIN2' -LdapFilter (CN=$Name)"`
| ft Location -HideTableHeaders
$Out = Format-list -InputObject $OU | out-string
$worksheetOut.cells.item($intRow,6) = "$Out"
    }
}
$objexcel.save()
$objExcel.workbooks.close()
$objexcel.application.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objExcel)
Remove-Variable objExcel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if `$OU` is equal to `$null`.  I suspect it just isn't finding anything if you get no error text or it doesn't take you to the catch handler.  Another option is to check `$?` right after the line calling `Get-QADComputer` but I suspect you will get True (command succeeded).  But if you get False, then that tells you it didn't succeed.